# Unable to add Azure AD Group as a user into Azure SQL Database

Tags: t-sql, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I want to accomplish the below task:

1. Assign X AD Group as user in database
2. Assign permission to full manage the database specificed to that AD Group

I am using the below queries:

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.DATABASE_PRINCIPALS --> Check/confirm If group exists in the SQL Database

CREATE USER [SQLGroup] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER --> Create the group inside the SQL Database

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'SQLGroup' --> Provide Reader access to the group
```

The above Queries works for an Azure AD Group that has MembershipType as "Synced", but fails for a Group with Membership as "Assigned". I am authentiating using Azure AD SSO. I am pretty sure that I do not have permission issues as I am the owner of the subscription and Azure SQL Database.

Error:

```
Failed to execute query. Error: Cannot add the principal 'Test-AnalyticsWro1', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

Comment: Just to confirm, have you created the Active Directory Admin on the portal? If you do not do that then the CREATE statement will not work.

Comment: CREATE statement works for AD Group that have "Synced" membership, but not for "Assigned" membership.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to MSFT and understood that this behavior is ByDesign. The statement is dependent on "GroupType" and not "MembershipType". If the GroupType = 'Office', the SQL Query fails. That is, it will not add that AD Group as a SQL user in Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Please proceed to mark your answer as the correct one.